# Filter ObservableCollection by value from Comma seperated string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, observablecollection

I am trying to filter an existing `ObservableCollection` by looking at one of its properties that holds a comma separated string, which I want to match against a string value and create a new ObservableCollection with matching results from this.

I have the following code at the moment but am a little stuck on how to use lambda correctly to do so

```
string s = "some string";

ObservableCollection<MyCollection> oc = myDataservice.ExistingObservableCollection.FindAll(x => x.KommaSeperatedString.Contains(s));
```

Not sure how to go about getting the desired result

As result i would like a new ObservableCollection with all objects that have a matching string in the ExistingObservableCollections comma separated string.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = oc.All(s=> s.KommaSeperatedString.Contains(s)).ToList<MyCollection>();
```

If you want to construct another `ObservableCollection`:

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyCollection>(myList);
```

Comment: this looks like it would work in theory, but how would i get the results from var list back to an observablecollection so i can use the data? Would this also give back the other properties of my Observablecollection<object>?

Comment: Your All should be a Where and you have two different names for your temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing against a string, you should try to convert it to a list first. Lists are far more flexible for this kind of filtering.

```
s.Split(',').ToList();
```